# Create new database login and configure it in code in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I try to create a C# Windows Forms project with .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework and SQL Server 2019.

Currently I create setup file with silent installation do all the work automatically and it worked perfectly.

Now I want secure my database after first run and creation. I want to create a new login on SQL Server, then assign it to my database. After too many try and error I used this code but I get the error because I do not know what is the `Sa` default password. I just find this (`RPSsql12345`) password as default in the internet.

Also I do not know if this is the right approach or not?

```
namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public class DACheckDatabase
    {
        public void CreateDatabase()
        {
            // Check if database exists
            if (!DatabaseExists())
            {
                // Create new database
                using (var context = new DB())
                {
                    string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-JU6B73e\\SQL2019;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=sa;Password=RPSsql12345;";

                    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    connection.Open();

                    string username = "test";
                    string password = "1234";
                    string createLoginQuery = $"CREATE LOGIN {username} WITH PASSWORD = '{password}'";

                    SqlCommand createLoginCommand = new SqlCommand(createLoginQuery, connection);
                    createLoginCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    context.Database.Create();
                    
                    string databaseName = "testDB";
                    string assignLoginQuery = $"USE {databaseName}; CREATE USER {username} FOR LOGIN {username}; EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', '{username}'";

                    SqlCommand assignLoginCommand = new SqlCommand(assignLoginQuery, connection);
                    assignLoginCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool DatabaseExists()
        {
            using (var context = new DB())
            {
                return context.Database.Exists();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my connection string in the `app.config` file:

```
"data source=DESKTOP-JU6B73e\SQL2019;initial catalog=testDB;User Id=test;password=1234;Trusted_Connection=False;"
```

Comment: SQL Server does not have a default sa password. The sa password is set during installation.

Comment: You've also got some SQL injection which you need to sort out, and `sp_addrolemember` is deprecated.